# Tensorflow model.trainable_variables doesn't update after setting layer.trainable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

#### Context

I'm creating a script which randomly modifies some parameters in a Tensorflow model. It aims to "encrypt" the model by recording the modifications made so that the modifications can be undone by authorised users only.

To enable this script, **I want to freeze all model layers except the one I'm manually modifying.**

#### Problem

To freeze all model layers, I set `model.trainable = False`. Then, I unfreeze a layer by setting `layer.trainable = True`. I want the layer's parameters to then be added to `model.trainable_variables` so that I can compute gradient updates like this:

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   pred = model(x)
   loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y, pred, from_logits=True)   
# returns None because model.trainable_variables is []
dloss_dparams = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
```

#### Reproducible Example

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
import random

# Load pretrained model
model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(
    input_shape=None,
    alpha=1.0,
    weights='imagenet',
    classifier_activation=None)

# No layers are trainable
model.trainable = False
print(model.trainable_variables)  # prints empty list: []

# Choose 5 random layers to train
selected_layers = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
while len(selected_layers) > 5:
    rand_index = random.randint(0, len(selected_layers) - 1)
    del selected_layers[rand_index]

# Attempt to make them trainable
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name in selected_layers:
        layer.trainable = True

print(model.trainable_variables)  # STILL prints empty list: []
```

#### Attempted Solutions

I've checked out [Tensorflow's guide on Transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning). Unlike me, they called `model.compile()` after they adjusted some layers' `trainable` attributes. But I'm not using an optimiser or evaluation metric; I just want to compute gradients and then manually update model parameters myself.

Some similar Tensorflow issues on StackOverflow are [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656935/keras-layer-trainable-false-to-freeze-layer-doesnt-work) or [based on bugs not applicable to my reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462707/why-trainable-variables-do-not-change-after-training).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

OP said in the comment,

> Before this is left for future readers as an accepted solution, I think it's reasonable to ask for more details on WHY this alternative works compared to the original method.

I did some shallow test and didn't inspect the source code of the APIs. I've noticed some unexpected behaviour of the `trianable` attributes, might be a possible bugs. I've opened a ticket, [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18092). In case you're interested, please see the attached gist file there, which contains comments and code.

---

You can try freezing the layers in the following way. The effect of `model.trainable` and the following way seems different, not sure if it's a bug or expected, will check and update here.

```
model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(
    input_shape=None,
    alpha=1.0,
    weights='imagenet',
    classifier_activation=None
)

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Choose 5 random layers to train
selected_layers = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
selected_layers = random.choices(selected_layers, k=5)

# Attempt to make them trainable
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name in selected_layers:
        layer.trainable = True

# check
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name in selected_layers and layer.trainable:
        print(
            layer.name, layer.output_shape, layer.trainable
        )

# not empty.
# you can do simply, model.compile()
print(model.trainable_variables)
```

Comment: ChatGPT also suggested this workaround (setting `layers.trainable = False` for all layers and then setting `layer.trainable = True` for the layers I randomly select. 

**Before this is left for future readers as an accepted solution, I think it's reasonable to ask for more details on WHY this alternative works compared to the original method.**